# Blender -> UE5 UVs Breaking

Tags: uv, unreal-engine

I’m trying to import an .fbx with ~2.7M faces. My workflow is Blender → Zbrush → Blender (for size and pivot point fixes) → UE5 (I also use Substance Painter for texturing but it doesn’t touch the UVs). I’ve checked the UV maps at each stage in this pipeline and the UVs look correct in Blender (just before exporting it for UE5). When I import the fbx into UE5 however, the UVs break.

I feel like I’m probably doing something simple wrong. Here’s a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!  Need to triangulate the mesh before importing it into UE5 :)

My workflow was best to triangulate and export the mesh from Painter once I was finished painting, but I also could've triangulated in Blender or Zbrush.  I'm not sure when the "best" time is to triangulate but doing it in Painter seems to work pretty well.